# Display two column by row bootstrap angular

Tags: jquery, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have an arrayData with 4 datas in my component file and i want to display it with two columns in two rows.

```
    myArrayData = [{id:1,pictureURL:'asset:mypict1.png'},{id:2,pictureURL:'asset:mypict2.png'},    {id:3,pictureURL:'asset:mypict3.png'},{id:4,pictureURL:'asset:mypict4.png'}]
```

`<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6" *ngFor="let cat of myArrayData; let index=index">
        <div class="card">
          <a href="#"  >
            <img [src]="cat.pictureURL"
            />
         </a>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>`

but it doesn't work; i want to have two rows with two colums.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this example? 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#equal-width-multi-row

Basically, you can "force" a new row by using the `w-100` class.

I would approach it something like this, where you will insert a new row element every 2 records:

```
 <div class="row">
   <ng-container *ngFor="let cat of items; let index=index">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card">
          <a href="#"  >
            <img [src]="cat.pictureURL"
            />
         </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="w-100" *ngIf="(index+1) % 2 === 0"></div>
   </ng-container>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hello @Victor G, i have the good result but the bootstrap card adding unnecessary white space (padding-left and padding-right). How can i remove it and  i want to add margin-bottom between two rows